# How can a footnote in a minipage use the same font for footnotemark and footnotetext

Tags: minipage

How can a footnote in a minipage use the same font for footnotemark and footnotetext. The mark in the example uses

```
\bfseries\sffamily\Huge
```

where the text uses the normalfont. The same does a "direct" footnote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{%
expl3,%   
xparse,%  
}

\newcounter{Foot}

\newcommand\Mark{%
  \stepcounter{Foot}%
  \footnotemark[\theFoot]%
}% Mark

\newcommand\Meaning[1]{%
  \stepcounter{Foot}%
  \footnotetext[\theFoot]{#1}%
}% Meaning

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Test}{O{t}D(){\empty}}{%
  \begin{minipage}[#1]{6cm}%
    \bfseries\sffamily\Huge%
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}%
    \setcounter{Foot}{0}%
}{%
  \ifx#2\empty\else%
    \setcounter{Foot}{0}%
    #2%
  \fi%
  \end{minipage}%
}% Test

\begin{document}
Start Text

\begin{Test}(\Meaning{First}\Meaning{Second})
  Word1\Mark word2\footnote{FN1}\\
  word3\Mark word4\footnote{FN2}
\end{Test}

After Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: John, it seems to me that reset@font is not called at all in this example. Can you show me in detail what your solution is. Thanks Jack

Comment: Inside a minipage \footnote uses a different counter, but \footnotemark doesn't.  \thefootnote should have no effect on \footnote inside a minipage.  Instead one should use \thempfn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\footnotesize` to control the size of the footnote text, while `\reset@font` controls the font type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{%
expl3,%   
xparse,%  
}

% modify \footnotemark to use same counter as \footnote
\makeatletter
\def\footnotemark{\@ifnextchar[\@xfootnotemark{\stepcounter\@mpfn
 \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}
 \@footnotemark}}

\def\@xfootnotemark[#1]{%
 \begingroup
   \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
   \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
 \endgroup
 \@footnotemark}
\makeatother

\newcounter{Foot}

\newcommand\Mark{%
  \stepcounter{Foot}%
  \footnotemark[\value{Foot}]%
}% Mark

\newcommand\Meaning[1]{%
  \stepcounter{Foot}%
  \footnotetext[\theFoot]{#1}%
}% Meaning

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Test}{O{t}D(){\empty}}{%
  \begin{minipage}[#1]{6cm}%
    \bfseries\sffamily\Huge
    \let\footnotesize=\Huge
    \expandafter\let\csname reset@font\endcsname=\relax
    %\renewcommand{\thempfn}{\alph{\csname @mpfn\endcsname}}%
    \setcounter{Foot}{0}%
}{%
  \ifx#2\empty\else%
    \setcounter{Foot}{0}%
    #2%
  \fi%
  \end{minipage}%
}% Test

\begin{document}
Start Text

\begin{Test}(\Meaning{First}\Meaning{Second})
  Word1\Mark word2\footnote{FN1}\\
  word3\Mark word4\footnote{FN2}
\end{Test}

After Text
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks, John. I guess it does what I asked for, but my question meant to be that the footnotes are in a font(size) _relative_ to the font in the minipage. In the example this is "\bfseries\sffamily\Huge", so the footnotesize might be something like "Large". But in reality the font in the minipage will be set by a user calling a macro and I don't know what it will be. Is there also a solution for this?

Comment: I could live with either the Mark/Meaning or the footnote solution. I don't need both.